# Extra space between Nav Bar and Image using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up my rails app with bootstrap installed to look something similar to the basic layout of the boot strap homepage or any of these two sites:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

https://www.gathercontent.com/

The part I am specifically having problems with is setting up an image at the top of both of these pages. There is an image directly under the navbar.  Then it splits and a new background separates the image/header portion with the rest of the website below (normally this is where the bulk of the content is).

I currently have an image for the top of my page but there is some type of padding between the image and the navbar (within that space you can see my main background).  I've tried adding a padding-top element with a negative value but it did not do the trick.  Does anyone know how I can get that spacing or padding so there isn't a space between my navbar and image?

Here is some of my code below:

_header.html.erb

```
header>
    <div class="masthead">
  <%= image_tag 'ctclogonew.png', alt: 'logo' %>
    </div>

  </header>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"


      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="#"></a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">

        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>

        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

styles.css.scss

```
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: #ff3600;
$navbarBackground: #ff3600;
$navbarLinkColor: #ffffff;
$headingsColor: green;
$heroUnitBackground: #00cbcc;


@import 'bootstrap';

.logo {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50em;

}

.masthead {
    background: url('basic background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    background: url('escheresque_@2X.png');
}

@import 'bootstrap-responsive';
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to tweak the following rule in `style.css.scss`:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

It looks fine if `padding-top` is set to `40px`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have added a plugin for twitter bootstrap called docs.css to your page, then you need to override it on your style sheet as body {padding:0;} because doc.css has set their style sheet as follows body 
{padding-top: 40px;}

Comment: Please take a look at [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Some simple formatting could strongly improve the readability.